# How can i make pagination works?

Tags: javascript

I would like to make pagination for the feed. For the first two next page is normal but suddenly the next page jump become 21. What is the cause? How can make the next page normal
{"total":"916","pages":92,"page":1,"next_page":2,"prev_page":false}{"total":"916","pages":92,"page":"2","next_page":"21","prev_page":1}

```
Here is the example of code
function reload_qlook_feed () {
   listing_refresh();
  var template = document.getElementById('qlook-test-source').innerHTML;
  var hbar = Handlebars.compile(template);
  var html = hbar( data_qlook_feed.data);
  document.getElementById('qlook-test-contents').innerHTML = html;
}

function listing_pagination(page) {
  let pg = {};
  pg.total = data_qlook_feed.data.total;
  pg.pages = Math.ceil(pg.total / 10);
  pg.page = (page !== false ? page : 1);
  pg.next_page = (pg.page < pg.pages ? pg.page + 1 : false);
  pg.prev_page = (pg.page > 1 ?  1 : false);

  return pg;
}

function listing_pagination_update(page) {
  let pg = listing_pagination(page);
  let pg_text = document.getElementById('pagination-text');
  let pg_next = document.getElementById('pagination-next-page');
  let pg_prev = document.getElementById('pagination-prev-page');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(pg));

  pg_text.innerText = 'Page ' + pg.page + ' of ' + pg.pages;

  if ( pg.next_page !== false) {
     pg_next.setAttribute('onclick', 'listing_pagination_navigate(\''  +  pg.next_page+'\');');
  } else {
    pg_next.removeAttribute('onclick');
  }

  if (pg.prev_page !== false) {
    pg_prev.setAttribute('onclick', 'listing_pagination_navigate(\''  +  +pg.prev_page + '\');');
  } else {
    pg_prev.removeAttribute('onclick');
  }
}

function listing_pagination_navigate(page) {
  listing_refresh(page);
  console.log('Pagination ( Page: ' + page + ')');
}

function listing_refresh( page, page_size) {
  page = (page !== undefined ? page : 1);
  page_size = (page_size !== undefined ? page_size : 10);


  _axios({
    url: "/api/call-ext/19",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      data: {},
      api: 'qlook-test?page=' + page + '&page_size=' + page_size
    }
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.data.status == 403) {
      console.log('HTTP 403: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data.data.message));
    }

   data_qlook_feed.data = response.data.data;
    listing_pagination_update(page);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its probably string and you have to parse it as int

```
pg.next_page = (pg.page < pg.pages ? (parseInt(pg.page) + 1) : false);
```

it's really easy to debug, had you logged the variables you would have seen the type conflict much easier

Comment: add it into another `parentheses`, updated the answer